# Feedback on a Small Trivia Game in C#

Tags: c#, game, quiz

I wanted to get some feedback concerning the program. It's console based and in C#. If I should try to add constraints like making sure only the 4 questions shown are able to be typed in and nothing else or uses a number system to retrieve and set answers and if to add a randomization. If I am to add randomization how am I to do so with string and methods? Was thinking of loading it from an external file where questions and answers would be read, randomized and printed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Trivia_Game
{
class Questions
{
    public void Question1()
    {
        List<string> Q1 = new List<string>();
        Q1.Add("Paris");
        Q1.Add("Spain");
        Q1.Add("England");
        Q1.Add("Portugal");

        string Answer1="";

        string TrueAnswer = "Paris";

            for (int i = 0; i < Q1.Count; i++)
            {

                Console.Write(Q1[i] + ", ");

            }

            Console.WriteLine();

        while (Answer1 != TrueAnswer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the Capital of France?");
            Answer1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            if (Answer1 != TrueAnswer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong answer");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct");
            }
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Questions questions = new Questions();

        questions.Question1();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Question class which include the question, the answers, and the right answer.

Then you create a list of questions hard coded / from file / from server ( what ever you want)

Convert the code in Question 1 to be more generic and work with the Question class.